# How You Punctuate This?

Tags: grammar

Once the seeds are planted, the soil turned and the cows fed, I can sleep.

Where would you place or remove commas?
How do you punctuate this.

Comment: It could always use an Oxford comma

Comment: I would suggest rewording it a little. I would say "Once the seeds are planted, the soil is turned and the cows ARE fed, I can sleep." or "I can sleep once the seeds are planted, the soil is turned, and the cows are fed." The second way takes out an extra and unneeded comma. BTW: Do you recognize this phrase from anyone? "Those do not love who do not show their love." -William Shakespeare

Comment: The sentence is ungrammatical. Once the seeds are planted, the soil **is** turned, and the cows **are**  fed, I can sleep.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth is (after the soil) and ARE (after the cows) are omitted because they are redundant. You don't need to use them *once* the be verb is used before them, **are (before planted)**.

Comment: You need a comma before *and* and everythign else seems fine.

Comment: @Rathony I have never come across an authority licensing ellipsis involving a verb-form different from the retained one (is after are here). This looks very mush like grammatical syllepsis. Can you find an authority allowing this?

Answer (score 2):

Once the seeds are planted, the soil turned, and the cows fed, I can sleep.